Managing environment related variables in Oracle Apex
How can I manage environment-related variables like values that changes based on whether it's dev or test environment etc. on Oracle Apex?
I tried using application item's set value and get value functions but it appears it only has scope inside an application and cannot be set from the schema. Is there any other way to do this?

What do you mean by "it appears it only has scope inside an application" and " cannot be set from the schema" ? Please update your question with as much detail as possible.

There are a couple ways to handle this. Suppose you have a parameters table with a record that contains the production status of the current instance. Values are 'PROD' or 'DEV'.
Then in the application you can

Use an application item (say G_PROD_STATUS with an application computation on new session ). This can be use used in server-side conditions of components to determine if a components needs to be rendered. Example (type: expression)

:G_PROD_STATUS = 'PROD'

will render the component if on production only.

Use an authorization scheme IS_PROD or IS_DEV that you can then put on components so they're only rendered in DEV or PROD.

An alternative is to create a build option called "Development Only" with a status on export of "Exclude". Enable the build option when you're developing - it will allow you to add debugging regions, etc. Because the status is "Exclude on export", any component with this build option will not be included in the production runtime environment. It's more powerful than an auth scheme. I'm a big fan of this approach, but it requires enabling the build option manually (or you could do it in a screen).


